# Static linking with boost python

Tags: python, c++, boost, g++

I'm trying to create a boost python extension but would prefer to statically link the boost python libraries. Otherwise you need the exact same version of boost installed on every machine you use the python module. I'm not using bjam though.

This works in linux (ubuntu) but results in dynamic linking:

```
g++ -o python_example.o -c python_example.cpp -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7
g++ -shared -o python_example.so python_example.o -lpython2.7 -lboost_python -lboost_system
```

python_example.cpp is just the basic example code:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

char const* greet()
{
   return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(python_example)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

Lots of google results out there which gave me a lot of things to try but nothing that quite worked.

Comment: Instead of `-lboost_python` give the full path to the `.a` file.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe put a

```
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB
```

on the top of your source file will help?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35440164/9358910

Comment: Please improve your answer.

Comment: Can you specify the way to improve it?

Comment: Your answer is presented like a question where you're not sure about the outcome.

Comment: Hey bro, I was asking the owner of this question to try this method. I am just asking for feed back, cause it is a easy solution :D