# boost python build statically

Tags: c++, boost-python

I googled around how to build statically but I am still struggling to run this. For example this [Static linking with boost python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29946400/static-linking-with-boost-python), I am getting errror

> /python_boost$ g++ -o hello.o -c hello.cpp -Wall -fPIC
>       -I/usr/include/python2.7 /python_boost$ g++ -shared -o libhello.so hello.o -lpython2.7 **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.a**
>   /usr/bin/ld:
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.a(from_python.o): relocation
>   R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8'  can not be used when making a
>   shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.a: error adding symbols: Bad
>   value collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Sorry. My question is what is the way to build statically like so that i can load the libhello.so in my python program. I tried various way to build and linked it but no luck. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object files intended to be linked into a shared library must be compiled as position-independent code. With `gcc` and `clang` that requires `-fPIC` compiler command line option. Static `.a` libraries are normally compiled without that option and that is the reason you observe this linker error. See [How to compile static library with -fPIC from boost.python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12418838/412080) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! it . works perfectly.!